# return documents that match from an array using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So basically i have a string of message and i want to get the document that matches the **keyword**

Tag to match: **Time, Family**

```
const sample_message = "This user have a challenge of Time and Family"

document_1 = {
challenge: Object ID 1
keywords: [ "Time", "Test" ]
}
document_2 = {
challenge: Object ID 2
keywords: [ "Family", "Test2" ]
}
document_3 = {
challenge: Object ID 3
keywords: [ "Foo", "Test3" ]
}



const result = model.find(keywords: { new Regexp(sample_message) })
console.log(result)
```

I need to return all the documents that match the keywords from sample_message which is the "Time" and "Family". Can someone explain the correct way?

Comment: So, what's the blocker here?

Comment: Should be as simple as `let keywords = extract_keywords(sample_message); model.find({keywords: keywords})`

Comment: basically i need to return the documents that match from keyword to the sample_message. I need someone to explain the correct way.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev but how exactly im going to extract the keywords. I believe using finding all and for looping the keywords just to match the sample_message is a bad idea.

Comment: There's no looping in my example. It queries all keywords at once. As to how to extract them, that is a domain-specific question that is out of scope here (we have no idea what constitutes a "keyword" in your app). To start, you can simply split the string on spaces, so that all words are keywords.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.model.find(
    {
        'keywords': {
            $elemMatch: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    $in: ['Time', 'Family']
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "values.$": 1
    }
)
```

Comment: why the nested elemMatch?

Comment: Furthermore, there's no need to use elemMatch at all. Array elements not objects and the query is one of simple equality. `find({"keywords": {$in: ['Time', 'Family']}})` should work just fine.